# AdminLTE 2.0(bootsrap) and Ruby on Rails template not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to ruby on rails in general and i now about the asset pipeline but i just can't get the adminlte template to work with my application.
The problem seems to be with the toggle options of the template.
[This link to the template](http://almsaeedstudio.com/preview) will show you some functionalities that just won't work with ruby on rails. I know my query is really vague but i hope someone can help me out

Comment: What have you done? What have you gotten to work? Have you uploaded your code anywhere?

Comment: I've integrated the css and it shows part of the adminlte template that i have modified to my needs. I haven't programmed anything yet.

Comment: So specifically what do you want that's troubling for you?

Comment: The toggle used to hide the left panel in ADMINLTE is not working, neither are the closing the div options. Essentially that's it. [Here's a link to the original template](http://almsaeedstudio.com/preview)

Comment: So essentially the part that's not working is the JS of the template. Totally forgot to mention that

Comment: Solved my problem. Solution(Super easy but i'm a noob in Rails) : Step 1: declared all my .js files on application.js as //require JSFILENAME. Step 2: used  <%= javascript_include_tag 'JSFILENAME' %> in the .html.erb file. Thanks for trying to help me out

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**(*Super easy but i'm a noob in Rails*) :

**Step 1**: declared all thye.js files on that i'm using with my project in  *application.js* as //require JSFILENAME.

**Step 2**: used  <%= javascript_include_tag 'JSFILENAME' %> in the *.html.erb* file. Thanks for trying to help me out